# Accessing sub-array and counting an element in arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have 2 questions about *arrays* in `java` and any help would be appreciated.

1. Is there a way to *access* a *sub-array* (something like this on `python: array[1:5]`)
2. I want to know does `java` has a function that *counts* a specific element in an `array` or not.

**I don't want to use for loops.**

Comment: *Why* don't you want to use loops? Even if a method exists in Java it'll have to loop internally.

Comment: I want to prevent long time order. I'm not sure that such functions actually use an internal loop.

Comment: So you're expecting something to compare each element in array of length N but in constant time? How would you expect that to work?

Comment: What do you mean by "counts a specific element in an array" ?

Comment: Amen - if you need quick (faster than linear-time) lookups, use a HashSet or a TreeSet.

Comment: Jurgen - Imagine I want to know how many 1 is in my int array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your first question, you can use `copyOfRange` static method of `Arrays` class.

Example use:

```
int[] array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] subArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 1, 3);

//subArray = [2, 3]
```

And for your second question, that method has to traverse whole array and that cannot be done without a loop.

Comment: shouldn't it be `subArray = [2, 3, 4]` ??

Comment: @BugsHappen No, `subArray` will include 2 and 3 because `Arrays.copyOfRange` method's `from` parameter is inclusive while `to` parameter is exclusive. So when you provide 1 and 3 as parameters, you actually tell method to return a new array from index 1 to 2 (not to include 3rd index).

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(int[],%20int,%20int)

Answer (score 4):

For accessing part of an array, you could use `Arrays.asList` to obtain a `List<E>`, and then use the `subList` method to obtain a slice:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six" };
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
        List<String> sublist = list.subList(1, 5);
        for (String item : sublist) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
one
two
three
four
```

For your second question: even if such a method existed, it would have to loop. I'm not aware of any such method in the standard libraries, so I suggest you write your own using a loop.

Answer (score 2):

The Java 8 way of doing this will be:

1. `Arrays.stream(array, 1, 5)`
2. `Arrays.stream(array).filter(x -> x == element).count()`

where `array` is your input `int[]` and `element` is the integer item to be counted

**Explanation:**

1. `Arrays.stream(array, 1, 5)` will return you a `Stream` object containing elements present in the `array` from index 1 to 4. That `Stream` can be further converted to `int[]` if needed using `toArray()` or can be directly used if some aggregate function is required on it like `min()`
2. `Arrays.stream(array).filter(x -> x == element).count()` will first convert the given `array` to `Stream` and then will apply the `filter()` filtering *out* any element that doesn't match the boolean condition specified and then will return the `count()` of the filtered *in* element.

Note: This or any other method for counting the number of occurrences of an item in an array will internally have to *loop* though the elements.